# I'm having trouble with using a NAS with After Effects

Tags: after-effects, hardware

Rendering files to my After Effects project from the NAS does not work. Also importing DNG files is not working. After Effects seems to be not able to write on the disk. The NAS is connected in a MAC via AFP. The NAS is Visible to After Effects as a Network Drive.

Error: After Effects error: File couldn't be opened for writing:"/xxx.dng".(3::0)

After Effects: CC2013 12.1.0.168

NAS: Thecus N5550 RAID 6 with 5x Western Digital WD30EFRX 5400rpm

NAS connection: tried AFP and SMB

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange! Could we have some more details please? How are you connected to your NAS (Ethernet?), what hard drives are installed in it (7200rpm?), what version of After Effects are you using (CC 2014?), etc. The more information we have, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice added some more info in the description.

Comment: Additionally, what actual error are you getting?  What are the specific symptoms of the problem?  Is the NAS simply not visible to the program?  Have you mapped it to a drive?

Comment: Thanks for your advice switched my AE to English and added the Error message in the question.